# Linear independence of the functions derivative

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are two linearly independet functions.
How do you prove that their derivatives are also linearly independent?

Comment: It isn't true ${}{}$

Answer (score 5):

Let $f_1(x)=1$ and $f_2(x)=x$. Then $f_1$ and $f_2$ are linearly independent (in the $\Bbb R$-vector space of smooth or arbitrary functions $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$). But $f_1'$ and $f_2'$ are linearly dependent

Answer (score 0):

It's not what OP asked for but the converse should be true.

Let $f_1,f_2\in C^1([a,b])$ be smooth functions with continuous derivatives and suppose that $f_1'$ and $f_2'$ are l.i.. Let $c_1,c_2\in \mathbb R$ be such that
$$
c_1f_1(x)+c_2f_2(x)=0 \qquad \forall x\in [a,b]\,.
$$
Observing that
$$
f_i=\int_a^x f_i'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\,,
$$
one gets for all $x\in [a,b]$
$$
0=c_1 f_1(x)+c_2 f_2(x)=\int_a^x [c_1f_1'(t)+c_2f_2'(t)]\,\mathrm{d}t\,.
$$
The above equation implies $c_1f_1'(t)+c_2f'_2(t)=0$ for all $t\in [a,b]$. By the l.i. of $f_1'$ and $f_2'$ one deduces $c_1=c_2=0$.